# Regex match and replace for abbreviations

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match and replace occurrences of u with you in the followings:

```
"my friend u.c.l.a i c u. c that thing? u c that thing?"
"u.s should see u."
```

The rule I am trying to enforce is that abbreviations shouldn't replace, so u.c.l.a remains u.c.l.a but every other u's should replace with you.

I am trying this with ruby, but this is not what I want exactly.

```rb
"my friend u.c.l.a i c u. c that thing? u c that thing?".gsub! /\bu(?!\.)\b/i, "you"
"u.s should see u.".gsub! /\bu(?!\.)\b/i, "you"
```

Comment: "my friend u.c.l.a i c u. c that thing? u c that thing?".gsub! /\bu(?!\.(?!\s))\b/i, "you"

Comment: @oldergod - good but the inner lookahead should maybe be (?!\s|$)

Comment: @pguardiario: Thanks for the suggestion. This handles my second case as well.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks for the notice, you're right !

Comment: @necrodome by the way, you should as well check if there is a space before the u or if this is the beginning of the sentence in case the 'u' is the last letter of an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

you regex pattern should look like this

```
    "my friend u.c.l.a i c u. c that thing? u c that thing?".gsub! /\bu(?!\.(?!\s))\b/i, "you";
```

Comment: these don't catch the second u.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
 "my friend u.c.l.a i c u. c that thing? u c that thing?".gsub!(/\bu(?!\.(?!\s))\b/i, 'you')
```

Comment: Thanks, this captures my first case. I forgot I have a case that doesn't involve whitespace. Edited the question to reflect that.